# Is it worth trying to seal these cracks in my driveway?

Tags: driveway, cracks

Cracks have formed in my driveway over the past couple of years. They are relatively thin - probably 0.5" at the widest point - but wide enough that weeds have taken root in them. There are essentially 3 separate cracks & their combined length has approximately doubled over the past 12 months. This picture shows the two largest cracks in focus, with the third (much smaller) crack in the background.

[image]

I live in a cold climate (New England) & I'm worried that ice will cause the cracks to expand. Is there a DIY fix I can use to prolong the life of the driveway / prevent these cracks from expanding?

Comment: They do make pourable products for filling driveway cracks.  What you use depends on what the surface of your driveway is - macadam, concrete, ...

Comment: Silly question. Can you tell what surface of this driveway is, from the picture? It was installed before we bought the home and I'm not really sure. I guess asphalt...?

Comment: @luke.samuel.mccarthy it's asphalt.  Get yourself some of the pourable stuff Steve mentioned, e.g. latex-ite 2X, or use the rope you melt with a torch.  You need to fill the cracks to prevent water from getting in them during winter.

Comment: I think that's the key.  Keeping water out so it doesn't freeze and expand, this widening the crack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You should kill and root out the weeds.  Then fill the cracks.
This will prevent water getting in there an expanding it further, as well as future weeds.
However, I am convinced that, in general, asphalt shrinks over time and this will be an ongoing chore.  So pick your battles.

There are a various products in the big box stores;
A pourable liquid, a thick paste for troweling, and some with stones in them.
These can be used in combination, fill the large cracks with stone, then trowel over.  The liquid can be used as a bonding agent as needed.

Act quickly, as they pull them from the shelves as the weather cools.  They are supposed to require hot days to set properly.  They have water and solvents in emulsion that has to evaporate out.  This also causes some shrinkage.

Also there are some in flexible stick form, that you cram in, then melt with a torch.  This product may bond better and shrink less.

Comment: Asphalt doesn't shrink.  The cracking is because of settling; the cracks get bigger because of freeze-thaw.

Answer (score 1):

Any unsealed cracks will soon have plants growing in them, which can apply as much force as expanding ice and which may be unsightly or become big enough to get in the way.

(I need to pour some vinegar over the cracks in my own driveway -- it's a cheap non toxic moderately-effective weed killer.)